# Is it possible to improve python performance for this code?

Tags: python, numpy, julia

I have a simple code that:

Read a trajectory file that can be seen as a list of 2D arrays (list of positions in space) stored in Y

I then want to compute for each pair (scipy.pdist style) the RMSD

My code works fine:

```
trajectory = read("test.lammpstrj", index="::")
m = len(trajectory)
#.get_positions() return a 2d numpy array
Y = np.array([snapshot.get_positions() for snapshot in trajectory])

b = [np.sqrt(((((Y[i]- Y[j])**2))*3).mean()) for i in range(m) for j in range(i + 1, m)]
```

This code execute in 0.86 seconds using python3.10, using Julia1.8 the same kind of code execute in 0.46 seconds

I plan to have trajectory much larger (~ 200,000 elements), would it be possible to get a speed-up using python or should I stick to Julia?

Comment: First rule of programming if its working then do not touch it, stay with julia

Comment: What is slow in the Python code? Can you provide the timings or make that reproducible for us to test it? The last line is inefficient and can be optimized. It is certainly the one that will be the slowest for a big input. By the way, what is the shape of `Y`?

Comment: you could impove some speed instead of using `range()` from python using `np.arange()` and actually accessing your elements with enumerate() for your first range(m) so that you aren't constantly doing lookups inside your loop when accessing Y[i]. Plus probably using np.mean() instead of mean() [though i don't know the speed gain on the np.mean()]

Comment: @JérômeRichard The shape of Y is n x 653 x 3 (atomic positions in 3D space). A collection of n snapshots consisting of 653 atoms with their x, y, z positions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've mentioned that `snapshot.get_positions()` returns some 2D array, suppose of shape `(p, q)`. So I expect that `Y` is a 3D array with some shape `(m, p, q)`, where `m` is the number of snapshots in the trajectory. You also expect `m` to scale rather high.

Let's see a basic way to speed up the distance calculation, on the setting `m=1000`:

```
import numpy as np

# dummy inputs
m = 1000
p, q = 4, 5
Y = np.random.randn(m, p, q)

# your current method
def foo():
    return [np.sqrt(((((Y[i]- Y[j])**2))*3).mean()) for i in range(m) for j in range(i + 1, m)]

# vectorized approach -> compute the upper triangle of the pairwise distance matrix
def bar():
    u, v = np.triu_indices(Y.shape[0], 1)
    return np.sqrt((3 * (Y[u] - Y[v]) ** 2).mean(axis=(-1, -2)))

# Check for correctness

out_1 = foo()
out_2 = bar()
print(np.allclose(out_1, out_2))
# True
```

If we test the time required:

```
%timeit -n 10 -r 3 foo()
# 3.16 s ± 50.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The first method is really slow, it takes over 3 seconds for this calculation. Let's check the second method:

```
%timeit -n 10 -r 3 bar()
# 97.5 ms ± 405 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So we have a ~30x speedup here, which would make your large calculation in python much more feasible than using the original code. Feel free to test out with other sizes of `Y` to see how it scales compared to the original.

---

#### JIT

In addition, you can also try out JIT, mainly [jax](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/quickstart.html) or [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/). It is fairly simple to port the function `bar` with `jax.numpy`, for example:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

@jax.jit
def jit_bar(Y):
    u, v = jnp.triu_indices(Y.shape[0], 1)
    return jnp.sqrt((3 * (Y[u] - Y[v]) ** 2).mean(axis=(-1, -2)))

# check for correctness

print(np.allclose(bar(), jit_bar(Y)))
# True
```

If we test the time of the jitted jnp op:

```
%timeit -n 10 -r 3 jit_bar(Y)
# 10.6 ms ± 678 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 3 runs, 10 loops each)
```

So compared to the original, we could reach even up to ~300x speed.

Note that not every operation can be converted to jax/jit so easily (this particular problem is conveniently suitable), so the general advice is to simply avoid python loops and use numpy's broadcasting/vectorization capabilities, like in `bar()`.

Comment: *"we have a ~3x speedup here"* It is 30 and not 3, isn't it? Fox Jax, it is even 300 and not 30 too. I think the `3*` can be removed by premultiplying the smaller input by `sqrt(3)` so it should be a slightly faster.

Comment: Oh you are right. I converted ms to s wrongly in my head! And yes, doing `sqrt(3)` apriori should be slightly more efficient.

Comment: Does jax use multi-threading?

Comment: It does. So does regular numpy I believe. Multi-threading is the default automated behaviour; to get otherwise users have to specifically restrict threads by setting flags for mkl, openblas, xla, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to do a comparison with Julia, and that depends on whether or not to use multi-threading. Unfortunately, installing jax on Windows was less straightforward than I thought.

Comment: You could request OP for his Julia code. I'm sure the code can be optimized in Julia as well; it should run at similar (if not even better) speeds.

Comment: @Mercury Numpy does not use multiple thread unfortunately (at least not yet for the standard package). Only level-3 BLAS operations like matrix multiplications are parallelized when a parallel BLAS library is installed on the target machine (Numpy uses OpenBLAS by default which is parallel). Note that packages like Numexpr can speed up Numpy expressions using multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

Stick to Julia.

If you already made it in a language which runs faster, why are you trying to use python in the first place?

Comment: Libraries are more developed in python, meaning that I will have less code to write in the future (clustering and other analysis I will have to do with the output of this code)

Comment: You can call any Python library from Julia with zero overhead using PyCall.

Comment: @StefanKarpinski, Also, in Julia, no one needs to avoid the `for` loops because they are fully vectorized. Furthermore, no need to 3rd party packages to perform vectorized array calculations 

Comment: @Antonello With m > 200,000 this will probably take a few days to compute using Julia. I will have to do that multiple times, also this will teach me how to improve my python code, this is far from useless to me.

Comment: @Okano: there must have been a misunderstanding. I wasn't criticizing your question, but the answer that is too much one side.. but I can't find my original comment, as it  seems disappeared..

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about speeding up Python, relative to Julia, so I'd like to offer some Julia code for comparison.

Since your data is most naturally expressed as a list of 4x5 arrays, I suggest expressing it as a vector of `SMatrix`es:

```
sumdiff2(A, B) = sum((A[i] - B[i])^2 for i in eachindex(A, B))
function dists(Y)
    M = length(Y)
    V = Vector{float(eltype(eltype(Y)))}(undef, sum(1:M-1))
    Threads.@threads for i in eachindex(Y)
        ii = sum(M-i+1:M-1)  # don't worry about this sum
        for j in i+1:lastindex(Y)
            ind = ii + (j-i)
            V[ind] = sqrt(3 * sumdiff2(Y[i], Y[j])/length(Y[i]))
        end
    end
    return V
end

using Random: randn
using StaticArrays: SMatrix
Ys = [randn(SMatrix{4,5,Float64}) for _ in 1:1000];
```

Benchmarks:

```
# single-threaded
julia> using BenchmarkTools
julia> @btime dists($Ys);
  6.561 ms (2 allocations: 3.81 MiB)

# multi-threaded with 6 cores
julia> @btime dists($Ys);
  1.606 ms (75 allocations: 3.82 MiB)
```

I was not able to install jax on my computer, but when comparing with @Mercury's numpy code I got

```
foo: 5.5seconds
bar: 179ms
```

i.e. approximately 3400x speedup over `foo`.

It is possible to write this as a one-liner at a ~2-3x performance cost.

Comment: That's pretty amazing. If speed is the end goal OP should definitely go with Julia. Also for benchmarking reference, the timings I posted are from [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com), which has 1 core / 2 cpus (2 threads per core).

Comment: `length(Y[i])` is calculated excessively. I suggest moving it before the inner loop.

Comment: For `SMatrix` `length` is known at compile time, so there is no cost. If it's a regular array, calculating `length` has a nonzero, but probably negligible cost.

Comment: I succeed to write a faster Python code, but I have to say this Julia version is quite competitive ;)

Answer (score 1):

While Python tends to be slower than Julia for many tasks, it is possible to write numerical codes **as fast as Julia in Python using Numba** and plain loops. Indeed, Numba is based on LLVM-Lite which is basically a JIT-compiler based on the LLVM toolchain. The standard implementation of Julia also use a JIT and the LLVM toolchain. This means the two should behave pretty closely besides the overhead introduced by the languages that are negligible once the computation is performed in parallel (because the resulting computation will be memory-bound on nearly all modern platforms).

This computation can be parallelized in both Julia and Python (still using Numba). While writing a sequential computation is quite straightforward, writing a **parallel computation** is if bit more complex. Indeed, computing the upper triangular values can result in an *imbalanced workload* and so to a sub-optimal execution time. An efficient strategy is to compute, for each iteration, a pair of lines: one comes from the top of the upper triangular part and one comes from the bottom. The top line contains `m-i` items while the bottom one contains `i+1` items. In the end, there is `m+1` items to compute per iteration so the number of item is independent of the iteration number. This results in a much better load-balancing. The line of the middle needs to be computed separately regarding the size of the input array.

Here is the final implementation:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(inline='always', fastmath=True)
def compute_line(tmp, res, i, m):
    offset = (i * (2 * m - i - 1)) // 2
    factor = 3.0 / n
    for j in range(i + 1, m):
        s = 0.0
        for k in range(n):
            s += (tmp[i, k] - tmp[j, k]) ** 2
        res[offset] = np.sqrt(s * factor)
        offset += 1
    return res

@nb.njit('()', parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def fastest():
    m, n = Y.shape[0], Y.shape[1] * Y.shape[2]
    res = np.empty(m*(m-1)//2)
    tmp = Y.reshape(m, n)
    for i in nb.prange(m//2):
        compute_line(tmp, res, i, m)
        compute_line(tmp, res, m-i-1, m)
    if m % 2 == 1:
        compute_line(tmp, res, (m+1)//2, m)
    return res

# [...] same as others
%timeit -n 100 fastest()
```

---

### Results

Here are performance results on my machine (with a i5-9600KF having 6 cores):

```
foo     (seq, Python, Mercury):    4910.7 ms
bar     (seq, Python, Mercury):     134.2 ms
jit_bar (seq, Python, Mercury):       ???
dists   (seq, Julia,  DNF)            6.9 ms
dists   (par, Julia,  DNF)            2.2 ms
fastest (par, Python, me):            1.5 ms  <-----
```

(Jax does not work on my machine so I cannot test it yet)

This implementation is **the fastest one** and succeed to **beat the best Julia code** so far.

---

### Optimal implementation

Note that for large arrays like `(200_000,4,5)`, all implementations provided so far are inefficient since they are not **cache friendly**. Indeed, the input array will take 32 MiB and will not for on the cache of most modern processors (and even if it could, one need to consider the space needed for the output and the fact that caches are not perfect). This can be fixed using **tiling**, at the expense of an even more complex code. I think such an implementation should be **optimal** if you use [**Z-order curves**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve).

Comment: Very nice, and quite impressive. The fact that both Julia and numba uses LLVM indicates that they should probably be close in straight code like this. Perhaps LoopVectorization.jl can improve the Julia version.