# Huge memory requirement difference between JAX 0.2.17 and JAX 0.4.1

Tags: python, numpy, jax

Follow up of the question:

[Is it possible to improve python performance for this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635970/is-it-possible-to-improve-python-performance-for-this-code/74636106?noredirect=1#comment131773811_74636106)

When using the functions from the accepted answer, with or without jax (bar or jit_bar):

```
T = np.random.rand(5000, 566, 3)
@jax.jit
def jit_bar(Y):
   u, v = jnp.triu_indices(Y.shape[0], 1)
   return jnp.sqrt((3 * (Y[u] - Y[v]) ** 2).mean(axis=(-1, -2)))
msd = jit_bar(T)
```

Sending a (10000x566x3) array to the function give me a stable memory usage of 1.5 GB with python3.6, with python = 3.8, 3.9, 3.10, 3.11 the memory skyrocket to +50 GB.

EDIT:

After some trials it seems to be related to jax only, this code will run fine with:

python3.6, jax (0.2.17), jaxlib (0.1.68), numpy (1.19.2)

but not with:

python3.11, jax (0.4.1), jaxlib (0.4.1), numpy (1.24.1)

Comment: Can you show how you're creating array *Y* ?

Comment: @Pingu Quite complicated, this is a numpy array (10000x566x3) with type f64, taking a random.rand(10000, 566, 3) array has the same behaviour

Comment: I have no answer (hence why this is a comment and also because I'm not a numpy expert). I can tell you that when I tried this on Python 3.11.2 with numpy 1.24.2 on macOS 13.2.1 on my machine (32GB RAM) it was killed by the OS because it was consuming far too much memory

Comment: @Pingu and yet I did (50000, 566, 3) which is five time bigger using python3.6 on my 16GB laptop and it ran fine...

Comment: This would be more productive if we didn't have to guess what code you're actually running. Could you edit your question to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem, including creating the data array and calling the function? (I don't know what dtype your data array is, or which function you're referring to when you say "sending an array to the function" because there are two functions in your question). It would also help to know which `jax` and `jaxlib` versions you're using. Thanks.

Comment: @jakevdp I edited the question as you asked, it seems to be a jax only issue, I deleted the numpy function because no version of numpy could run it without memory issues

Answer (score 3):

If `Y` is of shape `(10000, 566, 3)` Then `triu_indices` returns arrays of length `(10000 * 10001) / 2`, and so `Y[u]` and `Y[v]` are each of size `(50005000, 566, 3)`. If they are `float32` values, then that size is about 316 GB each. I would not expect this code to run well anywhere!

I suspect that older JAX versions may have had some additional optimization that was removed in later versions; given the form of your computation, the only thing that could have been is a factorization of the square difference to avoid instantiating the full matrix sum, which I vaguely recall was previously an XLA optimization but was removed because it's numerically unstable.

But you can do such an optimization manually if you wish; here's an approach that seems to work, and the largest intermediate array it generates for the original inputs is of shape `[10000, 10000]`, about ~380MB in float32:

```py
@jax.jit
def jit_bar2(Y):
   u, v = jnp.triu_indices(Y.shape[0], 1)
   Y = Y.reshape(Y.shape[0], -1)
   Y2m = (Y ** 2).mean(-1)
   YYTm = (Y @ Y.T) / Y.shape[1]
   return jnp.sqrt(3 * (Y2m[u] + Y2m[v] - 2 * YYTm[u, v]))

T = np.random.rand(50, 6, 3)  # test with a smaller input
np.testing.assert_allclose(jit_bar(T), jit_bar2(T), atol=1E-5)
```